# Javascript - How to change font size on any page in any element

Tags: javascript, font-size, tampermonkey

I have poor eyesight. So I want to enlarge font size on any page if it less than minimum. I am using "tampermonkey" plugin to automate this script. 
People either advising to find specific element and edit it like this:

```
document.getElementById("p1").style.font="italic bold 20px arial,serif";
```

or to change all fonts like this:

```
document.body.style.fontSize = "220%";
```

But it's not affecting text inside divs like in here(only titles are effected): http://mashable.com/
Should I iterate through all page elements or is there better way? Thnx

Comment: If you're willing to switch to Firefox, it has Preferences > Content >  Default Font: Advanced > Minimum Font Size built in.

Answer (score -1):

Your current approach is dependent on a site only using relative units (or inheritance) to determine what font size to use.

Given (not HTML, I'm using simple element names for ease of references):

```
<a> Alpha
    <b> Beta
        <c> Charlie
        </c>
    </b>
</a>
```

with:

```
b { font-size: 0.8em; }
c { font-size: 12px; }
```

Any changes you make to `a` will be used to calculate `b` (since `em` is a relative unit). However, `c` is defined using an absolute`*` unit so it will always be `12px`.

> Should I iterate through all page elements or is there better way?

I can see a couple of options for that rough approach.

1. Iterate through all the style rules (both `document.styleSheets` and the `style` property of every element in the page) and remove any references to absolute units.
2. Iterate through every element on the page, testing its computed style and setting `element.style.fontSize = "something !important"` as you go.

The problem is that both are going to take quite a while to run, especially on a large page (that's a lot of elements to test).

You might want to consider throwing out the default styles entirely, possibly by grabbing all the HTML from the page and then `document.write`ing it to clear the existing content.

Rather than write my own from scratch, I'd probably look at using existing tools on the market. I tend to use Mobile Safari's Reading Mode and Clearly for Chrome when I come across an article I want to read that has too small text or contrast problems.

Alternatively, Firefox has a Minimum Font Size preference.

---

`*` OK, so *technically* in strict CSS terms, pixels are a relative unit, but they aren't relative to the font-size of another element, so they are effectively absolute for our purposes.